Euler sum: $ S_{p,q} = \zeta(p+q) - \frac{(-1)^q}{\Gamma(q)} \displaystyle\int_{0}^1(\log{t})^{q-1}\operatorname{Li}_p(t)\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm{d}t $

Prove $ S_{p,q}  = \zeta(p+q) - \frac{(-1)^q}{\Gamma(q)} \displaystyle\int_{0}^1(\log{t})^{q-1}\operatorname{Li}_p(t)\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm{d}t $, where  $S_{p,q}$ denotes the linear Euler sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^{(p)}}{n^q}$.

I want to prove the symmetric relation of linear Euler sum:
$$S_{p,q}+S_{q,p} = \zeta(p)\zeta(q) + \zeta(p+q) $$
And this paper said that  I need to prove two propositions on integral representations of $S_{p,q}$ using the integral representations of Riemann zeta function and Hurwitz zeta function. That is:
$$ S_{p,q}  = \zeta(p)\zeta(q) + \frac{(-1)^p}{\Gamma(p)} \displaystyle\int_{0}^1(\log{t})^{p-1}\operatorname{Li}_q(t)\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm{d}t, $$  and
$$   S_{p,q}  = \zeta(p+q) - \frac{(-1)^q}{\Gamma(q)} \displaystyle\int_{0}^1(\log{t})^{q-1}\operatorname{Li}_p(t)\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm{d}t .$$
The first one is easy for me because it is simply solved by integration by substitution. However I got into trouble while solving the second one. The most confusing thing is that I did not know why there is $\zeta(p+q)$.
How can we prove the second proposition?


The key here is the following integral representation for polylogarithms of positive integer order:
$$\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}{\left(z\right)}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{z\ln^{n}{\left(t\right)}}{1-zt};~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\land z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)\land\left(n\ge1\lor z\neq1\right)}.$$
Suppose $(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}\land p\ge2\land q\ge2$. Starting from the first proposition that you've already proven, we then find
$$\begin{align}
S{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(p)}}{n^{q}}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{q}{\left(t\right)}}{1-t}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{1-t}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q-1}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{t\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{1-tx}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q-1}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{t\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{\left(1-xt\right)\left(1-t\right)}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{\left(1-xt\right)\left(1-t\right)}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-x\right)t}{\left(1-xt\right)\left(1-t\right)}\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left[\frac{1}{1-t}-\frac{1}{1-xt}\right]\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{1-t}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{1-xt}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{x(1-x)}\left[x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{1-t}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{x\ln^{p-1}{\left(t\right)}}{1-xt}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{p}}{\Gamma{\left(p\right)}}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{x(1-x)}\left[(-1)^{p-1}x\Gamma{\left(p\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}-(-1)^{p-1}\Gamma{\left(p\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{x(1-x)}\left[x\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}}{1-x}-\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{x(1-x)}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}}{1-x}-\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}-\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{x}\right]\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}\frac{(-1)^{q-1}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}-\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{x}\\
&=\zeta{\left(p\right)}\,\zeta{\left(q\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(1\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{q}{\left(1\right)}-\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}\,x}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{x}-\frac{(-1)^{q}}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}.\\
\end{align}$$
All we need to do now is show that
$$I{(p,q)}:=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(q\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{q-1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{p}{\left(x\right)}}{x}=\operatorname{Li}_{p+q}{\left(1\right)}=\zeta{\left(p+q\right)};~~~\small{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}},$$
which can readily be done by integrating by parts $(q-1)$ times, or by induction using the relations
$$I{(p,q+1)}=I{(p+1,q)};~~~\small{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}},$$
$$I{(p,1)}=\operatorname{Li}_{p+1}{\left(1\right)}=\zeta{\left(p+1\right)};~~~\small{p\in\mathbb{N}}.$$

~FIN~

All we need is the integral form of the generalized harmonic number $H_n^{(p)}=\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{(1-x^n)\ln^{p-1}(x)}{1-x}dx$, and the generating function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(q)}x^n=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_q(x)}{1-x}$.
\begin{align}
S_{p,q}=&\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{p-1}(x)}{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^n}{n^q}dx\\
=&\zeta(q)\zeta(p)-\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{p-1}(x)\operatorname{Li}_q(x)}{1-x}dx\\
=&\zeta(q)\zeta(p)-\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(q)}\int_0^1\ln^{p-1}(x)x^ndx\\
=&\zeta(q)\zeta(p)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(q)}}{(n+1)^p}\\
=&\zeta(q)\zeta(p)-S_{q,p}+\zeta(p+q).
\end{align}
Applying the same approach also gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\overline{H}_n^{(p)}}{n^q}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1} H_n^{(q)}}{n^p}=\zeta(q)\eta(p)+\eta(p+q),$$
where $\overline{H}_n^{(p)}$ is the generalized skew harmonic number, and $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function.
A different method to prove these two identities is by applying Abel's summation.
